# Validation for names using Regex for different types of names

Tags: regex, performance, validation

I have this RegEx code: ^([a-zA-Z]{1,}'?-?\s?[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?\s[a-zA-Z]{1,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)

I'm able to insert these names:

```
John Smith                                       
John Doe-Smith                                   
John Doe Smith                                   
Hector Sausage-Hausen                            
Mathias Sausage'd                                
Martin Luther King                               
Ai Wong                                          
Chao Chang                                        
Alzbeta Bara
ANDREW ROTARACT
ION-APOSTOL Marius Andrei
ION-APOSTOL Marius Andrei-Mihai
Cosmin Marius-Marian
Cosmin-Marian Marius
John Mc'Largy
Mc'Largy John
D'Largy John
John D'Largy
```

I want to be able to insert names with minimum of 2 letters. ie: Co St
I don't want to be able to enter these names: Co s, C St, Henkel1, Kenkel1 Nestle, 12344, Henkel & Henkel ( characters like &,.#%^*()!@~)
And also, I want to be able to add names like: John Mc'Largy

Comment: Relevant: https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: "*I want to be able to insert names with minimum of 2 letters.*" I know a guy who has a legal name which is one character long. However, because of restrictions like this one, he couldn't sign up with some companies simply because their systems would not accept that as "valid" even when it very much was. This includes electricity utility companies, so he was unable to even get an account with at least one company which meant that he couldn't *get electricity*. At least from that company - luckily, another one had less arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: Fortunately, our current customers have a name of at least 2 letters :)

Comment: And you're certain you will never get new customers? Or that any of your current customers will never change their names? The person I knew did legally change his, he wasn't born with a single character name.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /^[a-z-']{2,} ([a-z-']{2,}[ ]?)+$/gim;
const str = `John Smith
John Doe-Smith
John Doe Smith
Hector Sausage-Hausen
Mathias Sausage'd
Martin Luther King
Ai Wong
Mc'Largy John
Co St
Co s
C St
Henkel1
Kenkel1 Nestle
12344
Henkel & Henkel
Max Ap
Max Ap&
Andrew`;

const result = str.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you very much but still I can enter values like: M Andrew. I need to be minimum 2 letters for first and second name; and if I try to insert co ms, i can't because there are 3 minimum letters not 2 :)

Comment: thank you sir, now it's fine :) but I can add names like : John Doe Smith

Comment: What is wrong with John Doe Smith? It shouldn't be admitted? What is the rule behind that?

Comment: sorry, it was my fault, the code is fine :) I will use your code sir, thank you very much :)

Comment: Check it again, you can

Comment: now I'm able to add this name :) thank you sir a lot for your time and your kind support :)

Comment: Now I checked again all the names and I'm still able to add just 1 name(sorry, I didn't put this in my first post), but i don't want to be able to add just Andrew, I want to add his full name: Andrew Jonson or Matthew Race :) thank you alotropico

Comment: @alotropico my version works, but could indeed be improved further. So I update my version once more based on your adaptation of my solution :D Glad we're learning from each other.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^[a-zA-Z'-]{2,} ([ ]?[a-zA-Z'-]{2,})+$
```

How I came up with it:

```
PART 1
  [a-zA-Z'-]                                 = names with letters, quotes and hyphens...
  [a-zA-Z'-]{2,}                             = ... with at least 2 characters

PART 2 (double PART 1)
  [a-zA-Z'-]{2,} [a-zA-Z'-]{2,}              = there must be at least 2 name parts separated with a space
  [a-zA-Z'-]{2,} ([ ]?[a-zA-Z'-]{2,})+       = the last section can be repeated multiple times with an (optional) space in front of each part
 ^[a-zA-Z'-]{2,} ([ ]?[a-zA-Z'-]{2,})+$      = but nothing else on the line
```

Comment: ^([a-zA-Z'-]{2,}[ ]?){2,}$  this expression is the best :) you can add an option where I can add minim 2 names? I don't want to be able to add just Andrew or Nicolas, I want to be minimum 2 names like: Andrew Mathew or Nicolas Me. Thank you again for your support sir :)

Comment: Answer updated (basically repeat my initial solution).

Answer (score 0):

The regex for your requirement is `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z'][A-Za-z-]*\s[A-Za-z]{2,}[A-Za-z\s'-]*$`

Explanation:

1. The first character should be an alphabet
2. The second character should be an alphabet or `'`
3. After the first two characters, there can be any number (zero or more) of alphabets or `-` followed by a space
4. After space, there should be at least 2 alphabets followed by any number (zero or more) of alphabets, space, `-` or `'`

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/bDWa8m/22) for a demo and more explanation.